# Combobox will not display loaded store data

Tags: javascript, extjs, store, extjs4.2

I am using ExtJS 4.2 and when I print the `store` in `loadComboBox()`, the items are present, but they do not appear in the drop-down. The drop-down is empty.

Here is the [**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0pn3xzvf/5/).

```js
Ext.define('ReportFieldModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        'name': 'name',
        'type': 'string'
    }]
});

Ext.define('ReportFieldComboStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.JsonStore',
    model: 'ReportFieldModel'
});

var config = {
    'type': "Summary",
    'columns': [
        "red",
        "yellow",
        "orange",
        "green",
        "blue",
        "indigo",
        "violet"]
};

function processItem(item) {
    return Ext.create('ReportFieldModel', {
        name: item
    });
}

function processItems(data) {
    var arr = [];
    if (data && data.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            arr.push(processItem(data[i]));
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

function loadComboBox(combo, data) {
    var store = combo.store;
    var columns = data.columns;
    var processed = processItems(columns);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(processed, undefined, 2));
    store.loadData(processed, false);
}

Ext.onReady(function () {
    var resultsPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title: 'Results',
        width: 200,
        height: 400,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch',
            padding: 5
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'combo',
            itemId: 'myCombo',
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'name',
            mode: 'local',
            store: Ext.getStore('ReportFieldComboStore')
        }]
    });

    loadComboBox(resultsPanel.down('#myCombo'), config);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The config is `queryMode`, not `mode`.

Comment: Thanks, Sencha always changes the property names, I noticed.

Comment: I made 2 working JSFiddles after further investigation. [#1](http://jsfiddle.net/7ys8ypd9/1/) and [#2](http://jsfiddle.net/hgqse856/1/). They use an array store. The first one defines a new store and model, the other one defines them inline.